# mediawiki how to query for pages using a certain template?

Tags: templates, properties, semantic-mediawiki

I have pages which use this template:shape

```
{{shape|Shape name=ACTOR ROLE|Diagram 
type=ATD|Version=3.5|Shape=File:ACTOR ROLE V3.5.svg}}
```

i want to use something that choses pages with that template and select the ones in which the [[Diagram type=ATD]]

```
{{#ask: ?????????????
| ?Shape name=
| ? Version=
| ?Shape=
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing something in your question but you aren't querying for a template but instead the property value.

```
{{#ask: [[Diagram type::ATD]]
| ?Shape name
| ?Version
| ?Shape
}}
```

In Semantic MediaWiki you would also typically bound this into a Category. By adding to the {{shape}} template a call like:

```
[[Category:Shape]]
```

and then your query would get a bit more precise by adding that too

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Shape]] [[Diagram type::ATD]]
| ?Shape name
| ?Version
| ?Shape
}}
```

*Note: I'm assuming you are using property names that are the same as the template parameters. Typical convention with template parameters would usually store a parameter named `Diagram type` in a property called `Has diagram type`.*